# Can an overridden method be detected at runtime in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, reflection

E.g. is it possible to do something like this?..

```
export default class SuperClass {
    public method(): void {
        /* noop */
    }
}

export default class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public method(): void {
        /* useful work */
    }
}


export default class SmallerClass extends SuperClass {

}

let a = new SubClass();
let b = new SmallerClass();

/* Something like this?.. */
a.overrides("method") => true;
b.overrides("method") => false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
class SuperClass {
    public method(): void {
        /* noop */
    }

    public overrides(methodName: string): boolean {
        return typeof SuperClass.prototype[methodName] === "function"
            && SuperClass.prototype[methodName] !== this[methodName];
    }
}
```